# jQuery(this).attr('id') returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get value / id from anchor tag when clicked. Code seems fine to me but I don't know where is problem; it returns *undefined* or *nothing* each time.

Also tried `jQuery(this).attr("value");`, `jQuery(this).val();` and `jQuery(this).attr("id")`

Code which I have tried is following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <ul class="switch">
        <li value="1"><a href="#" value="1" id="1">link 1</a></li>
        <li value="2"><a href="#" value="2" id="2">link 2</a></li>
        <li value="3"><a href="#" value="3" id="3">link 3</a></li>
        <li value="4"><a href="#" value="4" id="4">link 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clickedId"></div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('ul.switch').click('a', function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();

                var id = jQuery(this).attr("value");

                jQuery('.clickedId').append(id+'<br>');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `jQuery('ul.switch').click('a', ...` this adds a click handler on the `<ul />`. If clicked the value `'a'` is passed as `event.data` into the event object. With [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) you can't use event delegation. Use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding event on `ul` not on the anchor. So, `$(this)` inside the event handler refers to the `ul`, and `ul` has no `id` and it'll return `undefined`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/656hc2pr/)

```js
jQuery('ul.switch a').click(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  var id = jQuery(this).attr("value");
  jQuery('.clickedId').append(id + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="switch">
  <li value="1"><a href="#" value="1" id="1">link 1</a>

  </li>
  <li value="2"><a href="#" value="2" id="2">link 2</a>

  </li>
  <li value="3"><a href="#" value="3" id="3">link 3</a>

  </li>
  <li value="4"><a href="#" value="4" id="4">link 4</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<div class="clickedId"></div>
```

You're confusing `click` with `on`, you can use [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) as follow

```
jQuery('ul.switch').on('click', 'a', function(evt) {
```

Comment: Yes @Tushar you are absolutely right I was binding event on `ul` only, that was the reason to get `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing `.click()` with `.on()`.

`.click()` doesn't take a selector, it binds the handler directly to the elements of the jQuery object.

`.on()` does take a selector, but also the event name as a string, like this:

```
jQuery('ul.switch').on('click', 'a', function(evt) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('ul.switch a').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var id = jQuery(this).attr('value');

        jQuery('.clickedId').append(id+'<br>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('li').click(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();

                var id = jQuery(this).attr("value");

               jQuery('.clickedId').append(id+'<br>');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You are clicking on UL not anchor tag So try this:

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(document).on('click', 'ul.switch a', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            var id = jQuery(this).attr("value");

            jQuery('.clickedId').append(id+'<br>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that executing properly. problem in your code is that you are trying to fire event on anchor inside UL tag

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="switch">
    <li value="1"><a href="#" value="1" id="1">link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li value="2"><a href="#" value="1" id="1">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li value="3"><a href="#" value="1" id="1">link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li value="4"><a href="#" value="1" id="1">link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clickedId"></div>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('li').click('a', function(evt) {
        jQuery('.clickedId').append($(this).attr("value") + '<br>');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```